# Use joint in both models

Tags: drake

I have two models, and I want to join the two links inside the two models (if I combine the two models into one, there will be only one parent joint).How should I do it?

Comment: We'll need a bit more clarity on the question in order to help.  Perhaps you can post your current attempt, and the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this. sdformat and mujoco's xml both let you include other model files, and should let you add joints between the links in the included files. xacro can also be used to preprocess multiple e.g. urdf files into a single file with joints across the separate links.  Finally, you could simply load the two models and then call the AddJoint method in Drake to add the joint across the models.

We have a tutorial [here](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/notebook/authoring_multibody_simulation-c37e49d0c5e04696a96f0fddafeaada1) that walks you through writing and visualizing these models. If you choose to use the sdformat approach, then it could be done with a relatively small modification to that tutorial notebook.